# Error: NullInjectorError: No provider for FlashMessagesService

Tags: angular, mean-stack, angular2-flashmessages

I am using **Angular 2 flash messages** to display message when user click on **logout** button. I have added **provider** in navbar.component.ts, and some other experiments but facing same error.

**Below are the steps which i have performed:**

**Step1:**

```
 npm install angular2-flash-messages --save
```

**Step2:**
**app.module.ts**

```
 import { FlashMessagesModule } from 'angular2-flash-messages';

    @NgModule({
        imports: [
            // other imports
            // ...
            FlashMessagesModule,
            // ...
        ]
    })
```

**Step3: 
app.component.html**

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>

<div class="container">
  <flash-messages></flash-messages>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

**Step4:
navbar.component.ts**

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FlashMessagesService } from 'angular2-flash-messages';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent {
  constructor(private _auth: AuthService, private flashMessagesService: FlashMessagesService, private _router: Router) { }

  onLogoutClick() {
    this._auth.logout();
    this.flashMessagesService.show('You are logged out', { cssClass: 'alert-info'});
    this._router.navigate(['/']);
  }
}
```

**Step5:
navbar.component.html**

```
<li><a href="#" (click)="onLogoutClick()" >Logout</a></li>
```

[image: Error Image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use forRoot() method returns an NgModule and its provider dependencies

```
 import { FlashMessagesModule } from 'angular2-flash-messages';

    @NgModule({
    imports: [
        // other imports
        // ...
        FlashMessagesModule.forRoot(),
        // ...
    ]
})
```

Check this:https://github.com/moff/angular2-flash-messages

Comment: can you explain why we need forRoot()?

Comment: forRoot() method returns an NgModule and its provider dependencies